# Как отправить письмо на почту с помощью Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp

Подскажите, понадобилось на python отправлять сообщение на почту yandex.
Нашел код, но вылетает ошибка.
Почитал, написано что ошибка может вылетать, так как пароль может быть не в кодировке utf-8.
Пишу в коде для password, addr_from, addr_to это:  encode(encoding='utf-8') - ноль эмоций.
Подскажите, как тогда исправить ошибку?

```
import smtplib  # Импортируем библиотеку по работе с SMTP

# Добавляем необходимые подклассы - MIME-типы
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart  # Многокомпонентный объект
from email.mime.text import MIMEText  # Текст/HTML

addr_from = "foo@yandex.ru"
addr_to = "bar@yandex.ru"
password = "pass"  # пароль от почты addr_from

msg = MIMEMultipart()  # Создаем сообщение
msg['From'] = addr_from  # Адресат
msg['To'] = addr_to  # Получатель
msg['Subject'] = 'Тема сообщения'  # Тема сообщения

body = "Текст сообщения"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))  # Добавляем в сообщение текст

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.ru', 465)  # Создаем объект SMTP
# server.starttls()             # Начинаем шифрованный обмен по TLS
server.login(addr_from, password)  # Получаем доступ
server.send_message(msg)  # Отправляем сообщение
server.quit()  # Выходим
```

Ошибка:

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: This user does not have access rights to this service')
```

Comment: а кто такой `send.msg.from@yandex.ru`?

Comment: почта, откуда должно отправляться текст

Comment: и пароль дан от этой почты

Comment: ну, то есть, это реальная почта?

Comment: реальная почта, Вы можете зайти на нее

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Только что была идентичная ошибка с почтовым акком на yandex для локального гитлаба. Исходя из гугления, обычно связана с использованием фичи, отключенной в настройках yandex аккаунта.

В моём случае помогло включить опцию «Портальный пароль».

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Путь к опции:

1. Нажать на иконку шестерёнки в правом верхнем углу
2. В выпадающем меню: «Прочие»
3. На новой странице в списке слева выбрать «Почтовые программы»
4. Поставить галочку на чекбоксе «Портальный пароль»

Answer (score 4):

Была такая же проблема, тут ответ - https://searchengines.guru/ru/forum/1037543.

Настроить ящик нужно:

> перепробовал всякое, решение оказалось не очевидным - помогла
> простановка галок в настройках ящика, с которого осуществляется
> отправление:  Почта->все настройки->почтовые программы
>
> разрешить доступ к почтовому ящику с помощью почтовых клиентов, раздел
> imap, я на всякий поставил там все галки в том числе в разделе pop3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ссылки-ответы не приветствуются, т.к. если ссылка станет недействительной, то и ответ тоже :)