# Django не отправляется письмо для сброса пароля

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я пытаюсь сделать форму для сброса пароля пользователя.
На локальном сервере всё работает и письмо отображается в консоли без ошибок.
На рабочем сервере ошибку не показывает, но и письмо не приходит.

settings.py для gmail

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'login@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

settings.py для яндекс

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smpt.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mail@mail.mail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

views.py

```
class MyPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
    email_template_name = 'password_reset_email_my.html'
    template_name = 'password_reset_form_my.html'

class MyPasswordResetDone(PasswordResetDoneView):
    template_name = 'password_reset_done_my.html'
    title = ('Password reset sent')

class MyPasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordResetConfirmView):
    template_name = 'password_reset_confirm_my.html'

class MyPasswordResetCompleteView(PasswordResetCompleteView):
    template_name = 'password_reset_complete_my.html'
    title = ('Password reset complete')
```

password_reset_form_my.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Forgotten your password?</h1>
    <p>Enter your e-mail address to obtain a new password.</p>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Send e-mail"></p>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: а если `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'` изменить на `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'` ?

Comment: если использую свою почту на gmail то получаю такую ошибку                 SMTPAuthenticationError at /password-reset/
(534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs\n5.7.14 YPnYi_t93btlXPmbkonM4mxnQyAGFJYqfQm2Q78QGcMf1IiriayjZNQssqVGJiXbp3B6s\n5.7.14 ZW-dJQqel9wTE-gvk8E59zSIDHOINzmThJWExXk9CbJx3mqwD26l8zLzc599dr2J>\n5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 q13sm13787lfn.15 - gsmtp'),  нужно как то добавить в доверенные устройства сервер

Comment: а если использую почту на домене сайта, то получаю такую ошибку     502 bad gateway

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255 откройте доступ к сторонним приложениям для gmail

Comment: доступ открыт и был открыт, об этом я знал. Но в любом случае мне нужно использовать почту на домене сайта, а для неё я использую яндекс

Comment: для яндекса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202125/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-python

Comment: применил данную настройку, но теперь другая ошибка                                        (553, b'5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.', 'webmaster@localhost')

Comment: DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL пропишите правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smpt.EmailBackend'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'mail@mail.mail'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mail@mail.mail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```