# Не работает скрипт отправки сообщения на почту

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

КОД:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.header import Header

sender_mail = "valased@yandex.ru"
sender_password = "1996kbpfvfvfgfgf"

target_mail = "vlad2012.ry@yandex.ru"

subject = "Privet"
msq = MIMEMultipart()
msq['From'] = sender_mail
msq['To'] = target_mail
msq.add_header('reply-to', sender_mail)

mailsender = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.ru', 465)
mailsender.starttls()
mailsender.login(sender_mail, sender_password)
mail_subject = 'Test mail'
mail_body_text = 'Privet'
mail_body_html = '<html></html>'
msq = MIMEText(mail_body_html, 'html', 'utf-8')
msq['Sudject'] = Header(mail_subject, 'utf-8')
mailsender.sendmail(sender_mail, target_mail, msq.as_string())
mailsender.quit()
print("Ok")
```

Comment: укажите в вопросе что именно не работает и если есть сообщения об ошибках - приведите в вопросе полный `error traceback`

Comment: Попробуйте ящик настроить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1203182/201445

Comment: @MaxU smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid user or password!')

Answer (score 1):

Для начала разрешите доступ для сторонних программам [Яндекс](https://mail.yandex.ru/?dpda=yes#setup/client). [Google](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

В случае с google по крайней мере Ваш код работает. (с настройками подключения от google конечно)